# lsort with increasing order of suffix

Tags: tcl

How to sort the following list

> GLU_43 GLY_8 VAL_11 ILE_13 TYR_15 LYS_16 VAL_18 LYS_36 ASP_19 LEU_20 SER_21 LYS_22 VAL_23 SER_25 LYS_26 GLY_7 CYS_27 VAL_14 GLY_28 THR_24 SER_29 LEU_30 GLY_31 GLY_9 ASN_32 GLN_12 ILE_33 HIE_34 HIE_35 PRO_37 GLY_38 GLY_39 PRO_17 GLY_40 GLN_41 VAL_42 PRO_6 LYS_10

as a function of increasing suffix as given below:

> PRO_6 GLY_7 GLY_8 GLY_9 LYS_10 VAL_11 GLN_12 ILE_13 VAL_14 TYR_15 LYS_16 PRO_17 VAL_18 ASP_19 LEU_20 SER_21 LYS_22 VAL_23 THR_24 SER_25 LYS_26 CYS_27 GLY_28 SER_29 LEU_30 GLY_31 ASN_32 ILE_33 HIE_34 HIE_35 LYS_36 PRO_37 GLY_38 GLY_39 GLY_40 GLN_41 VAL_42 GLU_43

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we use `lsort` with the `-indices` option, we get back the reordering of the list that we want to apply. This means that we can extract the second parts, get the sort ordering, and then apply that to original list to get the result we want.

```
set input {GLU_43 GLY_8 VAL_11 ILE_13 TYR_15 LYS_16 VAL_18 LYS_36 ASP_19 LEU_20 SER_21 LYS_22 VAL_23 SER_25 LYS_26 GLY_7 CYS_27 VAL_14 GLY_28 THR_24 SER_29 LEU_30 GLY_31 GLY_9 ASN_32 GLN_12 ILE_33 HIE_34 HIE_35 PRO_37 GLY_38 GLY_39 PRO_17 GLY_40 GLN_41 VAL_42 PRO_6 LYS_10}

# Get the suffixes
set suffixes [lmap item $input {  lindex [split $item "_"] 1  }]
# Sort them as numbers, getting the target sorting order
set order [lsort -integer -indices $suffixes]
# Apply the ordering to the input list
set output [lmap index $order {  lindex $input $index  }]
# Print the result
puts $output
```

I get this result:
`PRO_6 GLY_7 GLY_8 GLY_9 LYS_10 VAL_11 GLN_12 ILE_13 VAL_14 TYR_15 LYS_16 PRO_17 VAL_18 ASP_19 LEU_20 SER_21 LYS_22 VAL_23 THR_24 SER_25 LYS_26 CYS_27 GLY_28 SER_29 LEU_30 GLY_31 ASN_32 ILE_33 HIE_34 HIE_35 LYS_36 PRO_37 GLY_38 GLY_39 GLY_40 GLN_41 VAL_42 GLU_43`

---

If you are using Tcl 8.5, you don't have `lmap` and have to substitute with `foreach`:

```
# Get the suffixes
set suffixes {}
foreach item $input {
    lappend suffixes [lindex [split $item "_"] 1]
}
# Sort them as numbers, getting the target sorting order
set order [lsort -integer -indices $suffixes]
# Apply the ordering to the input list
set output {}
foreach index $order {
    lappend output [lindex $input $index]
}
```

The bytecode generated to using `lmap` in 8.6 is virtually identical.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the concise suggestion

Answer (score 1):

A version that uses `lsort`'s `-index` option and a [Schwartzian Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform):

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

set lst {GLU_43 GLY_8 VAL_11 ILE_13 TYR_15 LYS_16 VAL_18 LYS_36 ASP_19
    LEU_20 SER_21 LYS_22 VAL_23 SER_25 LYS_26 GLY_7 CYS_27 VAL_14 GLY_28
    THR_24 SER_29 LEU_30 GLY_31 GLY_9 ASN_32 GLN_12 ILE_33 HIE_34 HIE_35
    PRO_37 GLY_38 GLY_39 PRO_17 GLY_40 GLN_41 VAL_42 PRO_6 LYS_10}

set lst [lmap elem [lsort -integer -index 1 [lmap elem $lst { split $elem _ }]] {
    join $elem _
}]

puts $lst
```

Basically, it turns each element of the original list into a two-element list split on underscore, sorts that list of lists based on the second elements of each sublist, and then joins them again into a list of strings.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the concise suggestion!

Comment: @Prathit You should accept whichever answer you went with.

Comment: Currently the lmap command is not workinng with my tcl version, embedded with VMD. Therefore, I used the version with the lappend command. Thank you anyways...